# Record the time spent by an user in a page and send that data to a php file...?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Can any one help me in recording time spent by the user in a particular page? I also need to send that data to a PHP file where it will need to be stored in a database.

This is what I have so far:

```
var time = 1;

function timeHere() {
    time = time + 1;
    finalTime = time / 10;
}
function sayTime() {
    finalTime = time / 10;
    sendTimeSpent(finalTime);
}
function sendTimeSpent(finalTime) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Test/Timer/StoreTime.php?time=" + finalTime, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here i dont need any response from the server...

I just need to send the data to the server...

Comment: What do you have already and where are you stuck?

Comment: Does the data have to be sent when the user exits the current page? In that case, navigating through your website might become slow, since an AJAX request has to be made each time.

Comment: I wrote this java script but it is not working...
I dont know y it is not working...

Comment: @pimvdb 

Yes when user closes the page or request another...
In simple way when page unload it has to send the total time spent on the page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jQuery, but still I'm not fond on the idea.

```
var startTime = 0;

$(function() {
    startTime = Date.now();
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    $.ajax({async: false, // Necessary, because the closing code has
                          // to be suspended until the ajax succeeds
            url: 'store.php',
            data: {time: Date.now() - startTime},
            success: function(text) {
                // This is executed when the response has been received
                // text is response data
            }
           });
});
```

Comment: Using the `success` parameter, please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: You can't bind the beforeunload event using jQuery.

Comment: I placed an alert in that success function...
I cant see that alert when I close the page did this means ajax call failed...?

Comment: @pimvdb Please go through my updated question...
Here i dont need any response just need to send the data to server...

Comment: @Raviraja: What do you then want to do to check whether it finished? You can execute anything in the `success` part.